# How can I use SimpleIni to return wchar_t and then convert to std::wstring?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[SimpleIni Documentation](http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini-doc/html/index.html) says wchar_t is supported but I don't understand how to use it. This is what I tried:

```
CSimpleIniCaseW ini;
ini.LoadFile("myapp.ini");
std::wstring test(ini.GetValue("testsection", "testkey", ""));
```

> error C2664:
>   'CSimpleIniTempl::GetValue'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'const char [12]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your strings as L"testsection" << Note the L.

Comment: okay now I don't get that error anymore, but the wstring test is empty.

Comment: Problem was with the ini file's encoding. It only works if I save the ini file as ANSI.